# How to pass variable from batch to Javascript

Tags: javascript, batch-file, imacros

I have a batch file which checks how many picture are in a folder.
How can I return this value back to the JavaScript which calls the batch file?

```
dir /B /A-D /S "C:\Users\Viktor\Desktop\Images\*.jpg" | find /N /C /V ""
pause
```

Here is the code which runs the batch file from JavaScript:

```
var file        = null;
var process     = null;
var args        = [""];

// create an nsIFile for the executable
file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIFile);
file.initWithPath("C:\\Users\\Viktor\\Desktop\\file.bat");

// create an nsIProcess
process = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/process/util;1"].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
process.init(file);

// Launch the process
process.run(false , args, args.length);
```

Comment: You can't do that in JavaScript, but in node.js.

Comment: What do you mean pass to JS?  Do you have a node script?

Comment: As your folder in on your desktop, I assume you want to get this value from your browser... that's not possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "pass to JavaScript"? This isn't very clear. Copy and paste the results into a JS file? *shrugs* Unless those pictures are inside a web, then it's not likely you'd even be able to do this server side.

Comment: @Pierre C I have a code that runs Batch file from Js and i'm getting amount of pictures from folder i want pass this parametr to js variable, updated code

Comment: Looks like `process.run()` doesn't return anything. You may read about `process.runAsync()` which appears to return something... See: [process.run](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIProcess#run())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you need this batch file when you can use only your browser and imacros .js

Open the folder in your browser: `file:///C:/Users/Viktor/Desktop/Images/`

then run this .js in iMacros:

```
var img = new Array();

iimPlayCode("TAG POS=1 TYPE=BODY ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT");

img = iimGetExtract().split(".jpg");

alert(img.length-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect the result of the **dir** command into a new HTML file using the following syntax:

```
dir /B /A-D /S "C:\Users\Viktor\Desktop\Images\*.jpg" | find /N /C /V "">>yourFile.html
```

That will write the .bat result into your html.

Answer (score 0):

To return a variable value back to JavaScript, try re-starting your JavaScript file from that batch with found variable value as an argument. In the JavaScript file add a switch to bypass calling the batch again if that argument is defined.